# How to list all the rows of a Gtk.Treeview

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, gtk#

I'm having trouble grasping the use of GTK's TreeView and so I am running through some examples I have found online. Putting them together I am unable to work out how to extract the information in the view. I am operating the TreeView as a simple List with columns for the presentation of tabled data.

I am getting confused between the roles of models, stores and the actual treeview itself.

I am working from the example [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/advancedwidgets/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Gtk;

public class Actress
{
    public string Name;
    public string Place;
    public int Year;

    public Actress(string name, string place, int year)
    {
        Name = name;
        Place = place;
        Year = year;
    }
}

public class SharpApp : Window
{
    ListStore store;
    Statusbar statusbar;

    enum Column
    {
        Name,
        Place,
        Year
    }

    Actress[] actresses =
    {
        new Actress("Jessica Alba", "Pomona", 1981),
        new Actress("Sigourney Weaver", "New York", 1949),
        new Actress("Angelina Jolie", "Los Angeles", 1975),
        new Actress("Natalie Portman", "Jerusalem", 1981),
        new Actress("Rachel Weissz", "London", 1971),
        new Actress("Scarlett Johansson", "New York", 1984) 
    };

    public SharpApp() : base ("ListView")
    {
        BorderWidth = 8;

        SetDefaultSize(350, 250);
        SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
        DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };

        VBox vbox = new VBox(false, 8);


        ScrolledWindow sw = new ScrolledWindow();
        sw.ShadowType = ShadowType.EtchedIn;
        sw.SetPolicy(PolicyType.Automatic, PolicyType.Automatic);
        vbox.PackStart(sw, true, true, 0);

        store = CreateModel();

        TreeView treeView = new TreeView(store);
        treeView.RulesHint = true;
        treeView.RowActivated += OnRowActivated;
        sw.Add(treeView);

        AddColumns(treeView);

        statusbar = new Statusbar();

        vbox.PackStart(statusbar, false, false, 0);

        Add(vbox);
        ShowAll();
    }

    void OnRowActivated (object sender, RowActivatedArgs args) {

        TreeIter iter;        
        TreeView view = (TreeView) sender;   

        if (view.Model.GetIter(out iter, args.Path)) {
            string row = (string) view.Model.GetValue(iter, (int) Column.Name );
            row += ", " + (string) view.Model.GetValue(iter, (int) Column.Place );
            row += ", " + view.Model.GetValue(iter, (int) Column.Year );
            statusbar.Push(0, row);
        }
        // *** if I can dump treeview to the console here I'll be happy ***
        // *** I'd prefer a foreach or do/while ***
    }

    void AddColumns(TreeView treeView)
    {
        CellRendererText rendererText = new CellRendererText();
        TreeViewColumn column = new TreeViewColumn("Name", rendererText,
            "text", Column.Name);
        column.SortColumnId = (int) Column.Name;
        treeView.AppendColumn(column);

        rendererText = new CellRendererText();
        column = new TreeViewColumn("Place", rendererText, 
            "text", Column.Place);
        column.SortColumnId = (int) Column.Place;
        treeView.AppendColumn(column);

        rendererText = new CellRendererText();
        column = new TreeViewColumn("Year", rendererText, 
            "text", Column.Year);
        column.SortColumnId = (int) Column.Year;
        treeView.AppendColumn(column);
    }


    ListStore CreateModel()
    {
        ListStore store = new ListStore( typeof(string),
            typeof(string), typeof(int) );

        foreach (Actress act in actresses) {
            store.AppendValues(act.Name, act.Place, act.Year );
        }

        return store;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Init();
        new SharpApp();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

An array of actresses is created at the top of the code, and that is used to populate a ListStore (towards the end of the code) that is in turn used to populate the TreeView.

I want to iterate over the treeview's data and update the columns within it.

To this end, since `OnRowActivated` is a nice place to dump information, I'd like to dump out the entire treeview contents to the console when a node is selected.

Any help in guiding me to get this done (and hopefully understanding it in the process) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst certainly not elegant I found the answer which also updates some of the data in the model. I'd be happy if anyone could improve upon this.

```
            TreeIter iter;            
            TreeModel model = tv.Model;

            if (model.GetIterFirst(out iter))
            {
                do
                {
                    newYear = ModifyYear((string)model.GetValue(iter, (int)Column.Year));
                    Console.WriteLine("Updating: {0} -- {1} {2}",
                                  (string)model.GetValue(iter, (int)Column.Name),
                                          model.GetValue(iter, (int)Column.Year),
                                          newYear );
                    model.SetValue(iter, (int)Column.Year, (int)newYear);

                } while (model.IterNext(ref iter));
            }
```